# Determine bounds of continuous random variable CDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

If the continuous random variable $X$ has CDF $$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x\le a\\ {(x^2-3)}/{(x^2 + 7)},&a < x < \infty\end{cases}$$ determine the value of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $F(x)>0, \forall x$. Also since there is no discrete component in $X$, $F_X(x)$ should be continuous, and that happens when $a=\sqrt{3}$.